# Sprite-Kit Variable won't stop adding

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game I am trying to add 1 to a variable score every time certain conditionals happen in my update function. The problem is that the update function is called every frame so my score variable just keeps climbing into the hundreds when it should be going up by 1 slowly. Here is my code:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if circleStart.frame.width >= self.frame.width && userTouched == false{
        hasTouchedEdge = true
    }

    if hasTouchedEdge == true && userTouched == false {
        scaleSpeed -= 0.2  
    }

    if scaleSpeed <= 1.0 && userTouched == false { 
        scaleSpeed += 0.3
        hasTouchedEdge = false   
    }

    if userTouched == false{ 
        scaleSpeed += 0.1
        circleStart.setScale(CGFloat(scaleSpeed))
        circleLength = circleStart.frame.width
        acceptableBound1 = outerCircle.frame.width
        acceptableBound2 = outerCircle.frame.width - 100
    }

    if userTouched == true && circleLength > acceptableBound2 && circleLength < acceptableBound1{ 
        print("worked")
        isCorrect = true
    }

    if userTouched == true && circleLength > acceptableBound1 {
        gameOverLabel.isHidden = false
        playAgain.isHidden = false
        playAgain.run(fadingTapIn)   
    }

    if userTouched == true && circleLength < acceptableBound2{ 
        gameOverLabel.isHidden = false
        playAgain.isHidden = false
        playAgain.run(fadingTapIn)    
    }

    if isCorrect == true {  
        score += 1  
    }

    scoreLabel.text = String(score)   
}
```

What do I need to do or add to have my score variable work in my desired way explained above?

Comment: You're missing some code in your example. Where does userTouched get set? you should post that as well

Comment: If the score is being incremented every frame, then `userTouched` is true every frame. At a guess, that also means that `circleLength`, `acceptableBound1` and `acceptableBound2` are never changed. So, if the test that results in printing "worked" is true once, it would be true every time.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:
Add `isCorrect = false` after `score += 1`.

Good solution:
Try removing most of that code in update. Update is called nearly 60 times per second in most cases and it is not the best place to make changes for a few reasons.

Try using

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location
        if (someNode.contains(location)) {
            //This if statement isn't needed, but an example of how you can determine if a node was pressed
            someFunctionToDoStuff(location)
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first 
    let location = touch.location
    if (someNode.contains(location)) {
        //This if statement isn't needed, but an example of how you can determine if a node was pressed
        someFunctionToDoStuff(location)
    }
}
```

The first option may run multiple times depending on how many touches were determined. The second option will only pay attention to the first touch it notices and disregard the rest.

You can define this function however you like, just make sure to take the location of the touch if you need it:

```
func someFunctionToDoStuff(_ location: CGPoint) {
    score += 1
    // Then maybe move a node to where the press was located
    ball.position = location
}
```

You can use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded as functions.

Check out Ray Wenderlich's SpriteKit tutorials, you will learn so much! https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners